# Automatic Login from QWebEngineView to Website

Tags: javascript, python, pyside2, qtwebengine

I am trying to use the code below to create a view of a monday.com in a PySide2 app. I want to be able to login directly from the code instead of having to input my email and password. I have found some code pretty similar to the one shown below and adapt it to how monday.com's login page is structured.

I am currently able to enter my email and password as well as to click the login button. But, for some reason, it appears as if the page did not detect the entries although you can visually see them.

I've tried to put a second function that runs after "handle_load_finished" and included the JavaScript for clicking the button there but it would still run and not detect that entries were there.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

import os
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://miu2021.monday.com/auth/login_monday/email_password"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.handle_load_finished)

    def handle_load_finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            print("Page loaded successfully")
            self.browser.page().runJavaScript("let ap = document.querySelector('#user_email');"
                                              "ap.value = 'email@email.com';"
                                              "let pa = document.querySelector('#user_password');"
                                              "pa.value = 'password';"
                                              "let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];"
                                              "btn.click();")
        else:
            print("Could not load page")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

App Image:

[image: App Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the website detects the touch to verify that the user types and is not an automated task. A possible solution is to make Qt write by sending the QKeyEvents as I show below.

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QEvent, Qt, QTimer, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

KEYMAP = {
    "a": Qt.Key_A,
    "b": Qt.Key_B,
    "c": Qt.Key_C,
    "d": Qt.Key_D,
    "e": Qt.Key_E,
    "f": Qt.Key_F,
    "g": Qt.Key_G,
    "h": Qt.Key_H,
    "i": Qt.Key_I,
    "j": Qt.Key_J,
    "k": Qt.Key_K,
    "l": Qt.Key_L,
    "m": Qt.Key_M,
    "n": Qt.Key_N,
    "o": Qt.Key_O,
    "p": Qt.Key_P,
    "q": Qt.Key_Q,
    "r": Qt.Key_R,
    "s": Qt.Key_S,
    "t": Qt.Key_T,
    "u": Qt.Key_U,
    "v": Qt.Key_V,
    "w": Qt.Key_W,
    "x": Qt.Key_X,
    "y": Qt.Key_Y,
    "z": Qt.Key_Z,
    "1": Qt.Key_1,
    "2": Qt.Key_2,
    "3": Qt.Key_3,
    "4": Qt.Key_4,
    "5": Qt.Key_5,
    "6": Qt.Key_6,
    "7": Qt.Key_7,
    "8": Qt.Key_8,
    "9": Qt.Key_9,
    "0": Qt.Key_0,
    ".": Qt.Key_Period,
    "'": Qt.Key_Apostrophe,
}


def write_text(widget, text):
    for letter in text:
        key = KEYMAP.get(letter.lower(), Qt.Key_unknown)
        event = QKeyEvent(QEvent.KeyPress, key, Qt.NoModifier, letter)
        QCoreApplication.postEvent(widget.focusProxy(), event)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.load(
            QUrl("https://miu2021.monday.com/auth/login_monday/email_password")
        )
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.handle_load_finished)

    def handle_load_finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            QTimer.singleShot(100, self.write_email)
        else:
            print("Could not load page")

    def write_email(self, *args):
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript(
            """let ap = document.querySelector('#user_email')
                ap.focus();""",
            0,
            self.callback_email,
        )

    def callback_email(self, *args):
        write_text(self.browser, "email@email.com")
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.write_password)

    def write_password(self):
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript(
            """let pa = document.querySelector('#user_password');
                pa.focus();""",
            0,
            self.callback_password,
        )

    def callback_password(self, *args):
        write_text(self.browser, "password")
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.click)

    def click(self):
        self.browser.page().runJavaScript(
            """let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
                btn.focus();
                btn.click();"""
        )


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```